# Which Engine is more powerful?

Tags: engine

**Engine A Specifications:**

- Displacement: 1198 CC
- Max Power (bhp @ rpm): 87 @ 6000
- Max Torque (Nm @ rpm): 110 @ 4800

**Engine B Specifications:**

- Displacement: 1197 CC
- Max Power (bhp @ rpm): 82 @ 6000
- Max Torque (Nm @ rpm): 115 @ 4000

A brief explanation to answer will be much helpful!

Comment: Powerful how?  Power to get off the line when the light hits green with relatively low RPMs?  Peaks of power in high RPMs during a straight line drag race?  Power in mid RPMs for your typical aggressive daily driver?  Power coming out of turns in an odd gear?  Power up a hill with a small trailer attached?  Your question is like "What's the **best** fruit?" with no other information.

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski - You are mixing power and torque. IOW, you are mixing apples and oranges. Take the question at face value of "which engine is more powerful" ... taking the root of "powerful" to be "power", which would equate to horsepower, not torque.

Comment: @Paulster2 You're right I was mixing those terms.  I read it as Aaron knows enough to know that the spec listed `Max Power` isn't the full picture, hence why he asked this and listed the torque spec.  I understood powerful to mean "how the driver feels acceleration."

Answer (score 1):

### Engine A has a higher peak power

Namely 87 bhp vs 80 bhp. Both figures are achieved at 6000 RPM.

But a car doesn't always run at 6000 RPM, so it may be that Engine B has better acceleration as the engine goes through the rev range.

Answer (score -1):

To exactly address your Question it is **Engine A** as zaid suggests.

Hoping to give clarity on the engines themselves.

**Engine A:**

- This has a better power than engine B , you will find this engine better for in gear acceleration and overtaking manuevers also this engine will allow a higher top speed.

**Engine B:**

- This engine has better torque than engine A, you will find this engine better for city driving purposes since at slow speeds/RPMs its the Torque which is more prominent than the BHP. This engine will also have better fuel economy compared to engine A

Comment: Theoretically, it is true that engine A will allow a higher top speed. However, there isn't enough information to judge which engine will have better in-gear acceleration or which has a better torque characteristic. Also, fuel economy will be impacted by gearing more than the engine itself.

Comment: I am considering all other factors to be  similar for both engines/cars like gearing..

Comment: Even with that assumption, how can you be sure of which engine has the better torque characteristic? The max. torque figures are at different RPM's which makes it hard to compare them apple-to-apple. You really need a few more data points to be able to estimate what the torque curves look like. Two data points alone won't cut it.

Comment: Well yes... It is difficult to pin point the exact figures with the provided information  but I was not trying to give it in the first place..